# Prove that $\{\wedge, \rightarrow\}$ is functionally incomplete

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I know that I need to show that the relation $\neg$ can't be expressed.

I proved that the set $\{\wedge, \rightarrow\}$ is

- **truth preserving**: return the truth value **T** under any interpretation which assigns **T** to all variables.

If I take the assignment   $v$   that assigns **T** to any atomic $p_i$, so  $v(\Phi)=T$  for any expression $\Phi$ that consists of those $p_i$'s.

I am having problem to show the punchline: that any combination of $\{\wedge, \rightarrow\}$ is not equivalent to the negation relation $\neg$.

Can anyone help me finish the proof?

I tried to assume the opposite but couldn't finish the proof. Please advise.

Comment: Why not to finish the proof with Post's theorem?

Comment: If $v$ assigns **T** to $p$, what is $v(\neg p)$? Is that consistent with what you’ve already shown about $\{\land,\to\}$?

Comment: @VIVID Can't use it, unfortunately =\

Comment: @BrianM.Scott $v(\neg p)$ is "illegal" (as far as I understand).

Comment: @Dennis: You’re trying to show that it is not equivalent to any formula using only $\land$ and $\to$. $\neg p$ is not such a formula, but it still has a truth value under any given interpretation. And you’ve shown that its value under any interpretation that assigns **T** to $p$ is different from that of every formula that uses only $\land$ and $\to$, so  … ?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I understand what you mean, but I still don't see the contradiction. We said that any interpretation that assigns **T** to $p$ is true if the formulas uses only $\{\wedge, \rightarrow\}$. So $\neg p$ cannot be expressed - using $p$. Maybe we can formulate it somehow else? Sorry for the inconvenience, maybe I miss something more basic.

Comment: @Dennis: If $\varphi$ is a formula that does not contain $p$, then $v(\varphi)$ is independent of $v(p)$; $v(\neg p)$, however, is **not** independent of $v(p)$, so $\varphi$ cannot be equivalent to $\neg p$.